# Convergence of double sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_{i,j})_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be such that for each $k<\infty$, $$\sup_{1\leq i\leq k}|a_{i,j}| \to 0,\qquad j\to\infty$$
and
$a_{i,i}\to 0$ as $i\to \infty.$

Does it follow that $$\sup_{1\leq i\leq k}|a_{i,k}|\to 0,\qquad k\to\infty.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can have $$ a_{i,j} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 &\text{for }i=j-1 \\ 0 & \text{for }i\neq j-1\end{array}\right.$$

You have
$$ \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} a_{i,i} = \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} 0 = 0$$ 
and for each $k\in\mathbb N$:
$$\sup_{1\le i \le k}|a_{i,j}| = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 &\text{for }j\le k+1 \\ 0 & \text{for }j > k+1\end{array}\right.$$
so for each $k\in\mathbb N$:
$$ \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{1\le i \le k}|a_{i,j}| = 0$$
but 
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{1\le i \le k}|a_{i,k}|= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} 1 = 1 $$

Comment: Thank you, this was insightful. What if we also know that $a_{k_n,n}\to 0$ for every sequence of integers $k_n\sim n$. Do you think that this condition would be sufficient to show  the statement I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't think that would be enough. For any non-decreasing sequence $b_n$ such that $b_n<n$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n = \infty$ you could define $a_{i,j}=1$ for $i=b_j$ and $a_{i,j}=0$ elsewhere and it would be the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take for example $$a_{i, j} = \frac{2^i}{j}$$
This satisfies your first condition since for $i \leq k$ you have that $|a_{i, j}| \leq \frac{2^k}{j}$ which goes to zero as $j \to \infty$.

However $|a_{k, k}| = \frac{2^k}{k}$, so $\sup_{1 \leq i \leq k} \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{2^k}{k} = \infty$.